# Unable to Add Plugin to Redis

Tags: nagios

I modified a simple ruby plugin and am trying to get it to run on my redis server (not using npre to monitor remote hosts yet).

The command is in the redis plugins directory:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-79:/usr/local/nagios/etc$ ls -al  /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_redis
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios 4718 Apr 25 18:54 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_redis
```

And my commands.cfg

```
define command {
    command_name            check_redis_hash
    command_line            /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_redis -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p $ARG1$ -K $ARG2$ -o $ARG3$ -j $ARG4$
}
```

But I'm getting this in my log

```
[1429989009] Warning: Return code of 127 for check of service 'check that redis is up and a specific hash returns' on host 'redis_slave_two' was out of bounds. Make sure the plugin you're trying to run actually exists.
```

Do I need to do anything else to ensure the plugin works correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it would turn out to be something easy, I was missing the `'` symbols around the arguments, adding these resolved the problem.